# Hide and disable maximize button and disable double-clicking bar to maximize window

Tags: powershell, user-interface

I have the following Frame Settings in Powershell for my GUI.

```
$frmMainframe                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$frmMainframe.ClientSize         = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(449,385)
$frmMainframe.text               = "Yannicks Administration Tools"
$frmMainframe.TopMost            = $false
$frmMainframe.FormBorderStyle    = "FixedSingle"
$frmMainframe.startposition      = "CenterScreen"
$frmMainframe.BackColor          = [System.Drawing.ColorTranslator]::FromHtml("#ffffff")
```

Can someone help me disabling aswell as hiding the maximize button?
And is it possible to disable the double-clicking function on the Window bar to maximize the window?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the Maximize button like this:

```
$frmMainframe.MaximizeBox = $false
```

You can do the same for the `MinimizeBox`. To not show any of the Minimize, Maximize and Close boxes, you can do `$frmMainframe.ControlBox  = $false`. In that case, you need to have a button so the form can be closed.

To prevent changing the size when the user double-clicks the window bar, setting the `MinimumSize` and `MaximumSize` properties of the form might help:

```
$frmMainframe.MaximumSize = $frmMainframe.Size
$frmMainframe.MinimumSize = $frmMainframe.Size
```